# How to test if the type of the result is a javascript 'function' in Jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

How to properly test (using [jest](https://facebook.github.io/jest/en/)) whether the result is an actual JavaScript function?

```
describe('', () => {
    it('test', () => {
        const theResult = somethingThatReturnsAFunction();
        // how to check if theResult is a function
    });
});
```

The only solution I found is by using `typeof` like this:

```
    expect(typeof handledException === 'function').toEqual(true);
```

Is this the correct approach?

Comment: Yes; how else would you do it? I'd probably wrap up the check in something like LoDash's `isFunction`, but that's secondary (and because I almost always have a lodash dependency).

Comment: I thought that there is a way through the jest api, like `expect(result).toBe('function')` or idk something with **toBe**. Thanks for the answer @DaveNewton

Comment: That would be comparing it to the string `function`, which isn't what you want. There may be a function type matcher, though; I just don't know.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `toBe` matcher to check whether result of `typeof` operator is `function`, please see example:

```
describe("", () => {
  it("test", () => {
    const somethingThatReturnsAFunction = () => () => {};
    const theResult = somethingThatReturnsAFunction();
    expect(typeof theResult).toBe("function");
  });
});
```

Comment: Error: expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

Expected: "function"
Received: [Function anonymous]

Comment: Hi @Rob, just tested it now with Node v12 & Jest v26 and my sample still works. Please check your Node & Jest version. I used it in a blank file, nothing else except the code snipped from my example above.

Comment: @Rob is missing the `typeof` keyword. it should be `expect(typeof received).toBe(expected)`

Comment: Looks like this might be out of date?

Answer (score 21):

Jest offers a nice way to check the type of a supplied value.

You can use `.toEqual(expect.any(<Constructor>))` to check if the provided value is of the constructor's type:

```
describe('', () => {
  it('test', () => {
    const theResult = somethingThatReturnsAFunction()
    expect(theResult).toEqual(expect.any(Function))
  })
})
```

Other examples of constructors are: `String` & `Number`.

Comment: This seems like a much better way of doing things